# When I have a Windows VM, how do I upload my website to it?

Tags: virtual-machines, website, azure

This is a really stupid question, I know, but I have literally zero experience on setting up a website/web app from the server level - I've always used a third party like Arvixe or GoDaddy.  So, I have an Azure VM that I can remote into.  I need to (obviously) set up my website on it.  I've already installed IIS, so I would imagine that the website would go into the

> inetpub > wwwroot

folder, right?  Does one usually just copy and paste the files over, FTP, etc.?  What's the typical, accepted way to "upload" your website/web app to your VM?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not being asked by someone with knowledge on the subject, and is asking for setup/configuration help.

Comment: I'm sorry if it seems off topic - I do know about the subject, I've set up and configured the VM to what I knew, and was stuck on the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none - different people do different things. Depends on scaling. I never use wwwroot - I always leave that alone, stop the default website, make a new one. I rarely manually deploy - deployment is automatic.

When I manually deploy, it is often copy/paste via remote desktop or a file share. But then, most things I deploy are local portals for our internal application servers.

One advice - never upload a live website remote. This takes time - and you are down.

Upload to a staging folder, then run a script that deletes a backup folder, stops the site, renames current folder to backup, staging to current, starts the site, creates new staging folder.

This way your site is down a LOT less.